# power bi - return match with highest callNo

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables, outcomes and wages. They are related by a column called AnIDSurvey. The relationship is one to many... there will be many matches in the wages table for each entry in the outcomes table. In the wages table there is another column, callNo. I want to return the max callNo for each match on AnIDSurvey (at the moment I can only return a count of all the call numbers for each outcome).

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: if the datatype of callno is integer than you should be able to select the option "maximum" which is already available for visuals like table and or matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create this as a column, you can do that using variables:

```
Max CallNo =
     Var AnID = Table1[AnIDSurvey]
     Var MaxCall = CALCULATE(max(Table2[CallNo]),Table2[AnIDSurvey]=AnID)
RETURN MaxCall
```

Hope this helps.